# Impala Error when calling the Impala Thrift API ExecuteStatement: SSL_read: error code: 0

Tags: odbc, impala

Full error message: [08S01] [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (450) Error when calling the Impala Thrift API ExecuteStatement: SSL_read: error code: 0

ANyone has any idea, why this error is generated when one of my colleagues running his script , via impala to get some output data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a network or latency issue when connecting or running a hue query via Pyodbc(Python).
Just by rerunning the code again we can overcome it.

If you are getting this error frequently and want to handle the re-run via code then use exception handling.
eg.

```py
def execute_query():
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN:XXXX', Autocommit = True)
      impala_cursr = conn.cursor()
    try:
      impala_cursr.execute("SQL Query")
    except Exception as ex:
      if "error code: 0" in ex.args[1]:
        print("Rerunning the query statement again")
        execute_query()
      else:
        print(ex)
          
execute_query()
```